# Why can't I modify and do anything with my DB tables through vs2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, database-connection

[image]

When I connect my local DB with my project in vs2019 it says that my connection was successful, all good. But when I right click on a table and try to do whatever it pops up an error message with "Failed to retrieve server version".

Another thing that makes a problem is my connection in is:

```
public static SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-0R58GC3**\**SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SchoolDB;Integrated Security=True");
```

it  says that this part:

> Source=DESKTOP-0R58GC3\SQLEXPRESS

More particularly the \ is unrecognized, this is the error that it gives me after trying to build it:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1009  Unrecognized escape sequence    School
> Database  C:\Users\merti\OneDrive\Работен плот\School Project\School
> Database\School Database\DB.cs    14  N/A

Tried reconnecting and connecting a hundred times, tried to see of all my services are running (they are expect for SQL Agent I don't why but I can not start it).

Comment: Under normal circumstances, ** \ **will not appear in my connection, which may be why your statement will be recognized incorrectly. Use "@" with string to keep the special characters in it unchanged. Maybe you can try to modify the database name. It seems that you are not connecting to the local database of sql, I have never had such an error. Maybe "Работен плот" also had an effect, try modifying to English folder. If the answer below solves the problem, you can mark it as an answer, and of course if my comment solves your problem, I will be happy to turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslash \ is a escaping character used to deal with special characters.

For this reason, if you need to consume it as a regular character, you need to escape it:

```
public static SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-0R58GC3\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SchoolDB;Integrated Security=True");
```

Notice how it's duplicated. This is because I am using it to indicate that I am escaping the next character, which is itself.

You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/escape-sequences?view=msvc-170).

Comment: Thanks I did it right before this comment. It all worked when I debugged it and the built was successful, but only after I restarted my PC, then I tried debugging it for a second time and it crashed again, I again restarted my PC and it's fine debugging for now. Any idea why that happened?     ( for those who still can't make it work try using @ before the whole data connection string, example @"Data Source=DESKTOP-0R58GC3\SQLEXPRESS;.......)

Comment: @MrORE0 impossible to tell. I would recommend looking at the event log in your computer. You'll have information about the crashes there.
Don't forget to accept this answer if it is the solution to your problem.

Comment: I solves part of my problem, so I will leave it like that. Thanks for the info.